# Utility to map a drive letter to a secure FTP site (i.e. SSL/TLS)?

Tags: ftp, ftps

I know that Webdrive offers a utility to map a drive letter to a secure FTP site.

However, their software is pricey - and if you buy a license, it expires after one year so you can't use it any more! Thats just pure nastiness on their part.

Any alternatives out there?

Comment: Found FTP drive (http://www.killprog.com/fdrve.html) but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Found Red Drive - however, its been discontinued, and doesn't seem to work on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks promising:

http://www.expandrive.com/windows

"ADD SFTP TO EXPLORER

With ExpanDrive, you can securely access any remote file server directly from Explorer, or even the command line. No need to open a separate SFTP client just for file transfer. ExpanDrive extends the way all applications on your PC can access data."

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [netdrive](http://netdrive.net/). It's free for non-commercial use and does work with Windows 7. Options for SSL and SFTP are buried under the advanced button at the bottom of the application, but otherwise it looks like it does what you need.

Comment: Oh cool! I had no idea it supported SSL and SFTP. I'll check it out.

Comment: Not free anymore.